# SUMIFS with multiple criteria, one of which is a single day

Tags: date, google-sheets, unique, formula, sumifs

I'm trying to get a formula that will break down the amount of times a user enters a contest each day.

I'm pretty new to this whole thing, basically putting it together using google to figure out the code I need to use/modify. Explaining why something works would be greatly appreciated so I can use it elsewhere!

Here's [a dummy of the form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yaLxZ97ngcxWQTdDnSc1D2Le6BLnz-CguB3uOhGTLBM/edit?usp=sharing) I'm banging my head against.

I would like the form to be reusable, so on the Sorted form I have a date key that automatically fills out the week when you choose the first day. Because of this, I would like each formula to refer to this date key, instead of manually typing the google equivalent of 'February 1st, 2015' into the formula.

I've tried to use the SUMIFS formula, and I've run in to a few errors.

Apparently both pages have to be the same amount of rows, otherwise I get an 'Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size'. I didn't want my 'sorted' sheet to be 1761 rows long, since all of the duplicate names will have been condensed and I wanted it prettier. Nuts to that! Guess I can hide the rows? Is there any other solution?

It looks like this works:

```
=SUMIFS(Entered!E3:E1000, Sorted!E3:E1000, Sorted!$E3, Entered!A3:A1000, date(Sorted!$C7))
```

Where entered!E: is the number of entries, sortedE: is the list of usernames, and E3 is the specific one I'm looking for. Then EnteredA3 is the list of dates and time, and Sorted!C7 is the specific date I'm looking for. I don't get any results!

If I click on my C7 and sorted!A, the little calender pops up, which means they are dates (I think?). One includes the hours:minutes:seconds and the other doesn't, which I think is my problem. I would like to have sorted!C7 be the entire day, and filter out all of those entries.

This is taking information entered via a google form which I won't have control of, so I can't really change the H:M:S additions to the date column.

Thinking ahead to day 2 and onwards, will the same formula work when sorted!C10 is C$7$+1? Is it not a date anymore?

I would also like to add up the amount of daily entries, in sorted!S7 and below. I've tried wrapping both the column of dates and the date from my day key in the date() thing, but it doesn't seem to work either.

```
=SUMIF(date(Entered!A3:A),date(Sorted!C7),Entered!E3:E)
```

It gives me a '1', and I have no idea where that comes from.

I haven't been able to find much about the google SUMIFS function, mostly how to replicate it from before it was a thing.

And for even MORE complexity:

I was wondering if it is possible to have UNIQUE find the IDs in entered!C, and return all the associated usernames. That pesky angelo changed their username to 'pants' midway through the contest, and I'd like to be able to see both names and add up both 'angelo' and 'pants' entries in the same line in my formulas.

I feel like I'll need a few hidden columns that have the UNIQUE ID number and the associated usernames that I pull into my Sorted!Username column, but I don't know how to search the IDs to find the different usernames.

I tried to google that, but I have no idea what I'm googling.

Whewph! That is a lot of questions, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for my taste, but you might try:

```
=sumifs(Entered!E:E,Entered!A:A,">="&$C$7,Entered!A:A,"<"&$C$7+1,Entered!B:B,$E3)
```

in Sorted!F3 and copied down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness, you are a hero!

My final code wound up being:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sorted!$E3)=TRUE, "", sumifs('Entered'!$E:$E,'Entered'!$A:$A,">="&$C$7,'Entered'!$A:$A,"<"&$C$7+1,'Entered'!$B:$B,$E3))
```

I changed the start and end points by making $C$7 into $C$7+1, and the ending one into +2. (In case anyone else is looking at this answer.)

I'm super pleased that it worked!

Using this I managed to add up each of the daily entries, just by adding up the columns they were in.

I gave up on the UNIQUE idea, if someone changes their username during the contest, then they can add up the two rows themselves.

Thanks again! I'd upvote you, but I can't yet.